# I get the following error when import CSV to a table in Heidi SQL "SQL Error: Data truncated for column 'SlNo' at row 1"

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I have saved a dataframe (pandas) in python as a CSV file and am trying to import it into a table using Heidi SQL and I get the error "SQL Error: Data truncated for column 'SlNo' at row 1".
Here is the error:
[image: The error message]

Here is my table:
[image: Here is the table]

And this is the CSV file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qDfkTNZNTOKTSpnia3CFoW1ahHm6LQ5v

Comment: It would help of you added the first few lines of the csv file as text to the question.

Comment: I have attached a link to the CSV file. You can download it.

Comment: I could but it's two stages away from your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fields in your csv file separated by comma, you have to specify "," (comma) as field terminator on import dialog instead of ";" (semicolon).